# How can I add a comma before and after each phone number in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I add a comma before and after every phone number in each cell in excel?

So I have a combination of words and multiple phone numbers in a single cell in excel, and I would like to place a comma before and after each phone number. Anyone know how I can do that?
The format of the phone numbers is: ###-###-####

An example of one cell:
Marie (headquarters office) ###-###-####
George mobile ###-###-###
Stan (president) ###-###-####

I'm using Excel for Mac 2019

Answer (score 3):

Office 365 formula:

```
=LET(
    ζ, A1,
    ξ, TEXTSPLIT(ζ, " "),
    ψ, FILTER(ξ, 1 - ISERR(SEARCH("???-???-????", ξ))),
    δ, CONCAT(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(ζ, ψ, , 1)) & ", " & ψ & ", "),
    LEFT(δ, LEN(δ) - 2)
)
```

Assumes that all substrings of the form "###-###-####" relate to phone numbers.

Comment: This did not work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It works for the example you posted, and has been upvoted three times, so suggest you clarify *why* it doesn't work for you.

Comment: it worked for me, i tried just now with the example posted

Comment: I'm getting the error message "Alert, that the function isn't valid" because im running Excel 2019 for Mac and the LET function is not available on that version...do you have something else?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a single column of data, you can do this:

**1.** copy your data to Notepad++

**2.** press **Ctrl+H**, setup the find and replace like so and select replace all. Make sure you check "regular expression" at the bottom left.

[image]

```
\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}
,$&,
```

**3.** done! Now just copy your data back to excel. Unfortunately, excel doesn't support regular expressions natively as far as I know. You can make them work using VBA but I think this solution works better as long as it's a one-time operation and you don't need to do this often.

**note:** You can do the same in Google Sheets but as @Lord-JulianXLII pointed out, this is probably not advisable as you are uploading private information online.

Comment: depending on privacy laws (and location) this solution is a big no-no.

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII Didn't think of that. Do you think I should just delete it or...?

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII I looked around and google sheets appears to be safe: https://blog.golayer.io/google-sheets/how-secure-is-google-sheets Not sure if you can trust this particular site but others seem to agree as well. I'm pretty sure using my solution is OK but I'm no cyber-security expert, so this option should be used at one's own discretion.

Comment: yeah but it is a cloud based spreadsheet. The problem is not that google sheets is inherently unsafe, but the data you input will be stored on googles servers. If your company is located in the EU you are bound by the DSGVO and local laws. And just willy nilly uploading personal data to some server in the US, is pretty risky business. (Especially since I'm pretty sure you didn't get the customers consent beforehand). - If it's just your own personal data, go for it. Or if you'r sure your countries laws have no problem with it. But if your unsure just don't - it's not worth the headache.

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII Thank you for the explanation. I reworked my answer to use Notepad++ and just added the google sheet option as a note at the bottom.